# Error with like box cant show it

Tags: iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetParent' of null getnetworkwidget:157
146
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetParent' of null getnetworkwidget:157
networkedblogs.getElemTop getnetworkwidget:157
networkedblogs.checkVisibility

is dispalyed and cannot be seen. like box not displayed